# How to retrieve whole words instead of single chars from pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm reading a pattern from unique names of a TSV file (efficiency doesn't matter at this point):

```
while (dataRow != null) {
    String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
    String name = dataArray[1];
    combined += Pattern.quote(name.replace("\"", "")) + "|";

    dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
}
Pattern all = Pattern.compile(combined);
```

Using `quote()` was necessary because of `Regex` characters in the names.

Now I'm matching the `Pattern` against an input text:

```
Matcher m = all.matcher(input);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
```

`matches` contains space characters, single characters, parts of words, and also whole words, however I only want whole words to be matched. More exactly: I want the longest substring to be matched that is at least one word. Of course I could postprocess everything in the last `while` loop but this is not the sense of `Matcher`.

Comment: Your last alternative is empty since you append `|` to the end of the pattern with each iteration. Trim it off (`substring` will do) from the final expression and check again.

Comment: This would explain the empty characters, but not the other ones. Or does it?

Comment: How can I know that? What is the example input? What is the regex you obtain? If you shared that, I could have posted an answer a minute or two ago already.

Comment: Well, the thing is the TSV file contains a couple of million names and it's hard to reconstruct the exact case. I was hoping for easy mistakes like the `|` at the end ;) Thank you

Comment: Please check if that works and let know if it solved the issue. Use `combined = combined.substring(0, combined.length() - 1);` to trim it after it is ready.

Comment: post your regex, a few -small- example input strings, and your desired output ... right now you are having people shoot at a target while blindfolded

Comment: Well, how I construct the `Regex`, you can see above. The resulting `Pattern` starts with: `\QTom Fitzpatrick\E|\QBenjamin Cohen\E|\QJames Sallis\E|...` and ends with `\QGoogle Contacts Data API\E` with a million names in between. Input Strings are English newstexts. Does this help??? @stribizhev : The problem is still there, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: To get the longest match, before building a regex, get a list of all the names with `Pattern.quote`, sort the list by length, from longest to shortest, then, join with `|` to one string, add `(?<=\\w)(?:` in the beginning and `)(?!\\w)` in the end so that the regex looked like `(?<!\\w)(?:\\Qname1\\E|\\Qname2\\E|....)(?!\w)`.